# cannot convert value of type 'Range<Int32>' to expected argument type 'Range<_>'

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

```
@IBAction func Guess(_ sender: UIButton) {
        var R1 = (Range1.text!as NSString).intValue
        var R2 = (Range2.text! as NSString).intValue
        //print(R1, " ", R2)
        
        var answer = Int.random(in: R1..<R2)
```

I want to generate random number from the range given by the user through TextField.

Comment: You have not provided enough information. How are the variables `Range1` and `Range2` declared?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has quite a few problems (Leo covered some of them in his answer, but listing everything for completeness.)

1. Don't use variable names starting with capital letters
2. Use Swift types rather than Objective-C "NS" types
3. The NSString `intValue` property returns an Int32, and you need Int type

Try this code instead which uses native Swift types and proper variable naming:

```
let text1 = "7"
let text2 = "13"
if let r1 = Int(text1),
   let r2 = Int(text2),
   r1 < r2 {
    let answer = Int.random(in: r1..<r2)
    print("random answer = \(answer)")
} else {
    print("Could not convert '\(text1)' or '\(text2)' to an Int")
}
```

---

### Edit:

Rewriting the above as a function, with about 500 pounds of error checking:

```
@discardableResult func randomValue(lowerString: String?, upperString: String?) -> Int? {
    guard let lowerNonNilString = lowerString,
          let upperNonNilString = upperString else {
        print("One or more inputs is nil")
        return nil
    }
    guard let lower = Int(lowerNonNilString) else {
        print("'\(lowerNonNilString)' cannot be converted to an Int")
        return nil
    }
    guard let upper = Int(upperNonNilString) else {
        print("'\(upperNonNilString)' cannot be converted to an Int")
        return nil
    }
    guard lower < upper else {
        print("\(lower) must be less than \(upper)")
        return nil
    }
    let result = Int.random(in: lower..<upper)
    print("random value between '\(lowerNonNilString)' and '\(upperNonNilString)' is \(result)")
    return result
}

randomValue(lowerString: nil, upperString: "13")
randomValue(lowerString: "07", upperString: "13")
randomValue(lowerString: "13", upperString: "7")
randomValue(lowerString: "7", upperString: "7")
randomValue(lowerString: "7", upperString: "8")
randomValue(lowerString: "foo", upperString: "7")
randomValue(lowerString: "7", upperString: "bar")
```

That outputs:

```
One or more inputs is nil
random value between '07' and '13' is 10
13 must be less than 7
7 must be less than 7
random value between '7' and '8' is 7
'foo' cannot be converted to an Int
'bar' cannot be converted to an Int
```

Comment: Note that this might crash if the upper bound is less than or equal to  the lower bound

Comment: Yup. I fixed it.